# Как отследить падение postgresql

Tags: linux, база-данных, ubuntu, postgresql, jdbc

Postgres запущен на удаленном linux серевере. Бэк Spring Boot обращается к этой БД. Бэк пока крутится в докере и обращается к postgres развернутой на сервере с публичным доступом по паролю. База периодически падает, не понимаю как отследить из-за чего она падает. Пробовал добавлять логирование в бэк и постгрес.

После рестарта postgres всё снова работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Логи postgres'a:

```
2023-05-08 09:40:43.513 CEST [2287947] postgres@spot_map LOG:  duration: 18.641 ms
2023-05-08 09:40:48.528 CEST [2287947] postgres@spot_map LOG:  duration: 7.177 ms
2023-05-08 09:40:49.932 CEST [2287891] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-05-08 09:40:49.934 CEST [2287891] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-05-08 09:40:49.935 CEST [2288934] postgres@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.936 CEST [2288640] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.936 CEST [2288934] postgres@postgres LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:03:55.596 user=postgres database=postgres host=78.139.198.206 port=30708
2023-05-08 09:40:49.936 CEST [2288640] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:18.333 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=38548
2023-05-08 09:40:49.937 CEST [2288913] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.937 CEST [2288945] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.938 CEST [2288945] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:03:44.432 user=postgres database=spot_map host=78.139.198.206 port=30782
2023-05-08 09:40:49.938 CEST [2288913] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:04:02.333 user=postgres database=spot_map host=78.139.198.206 port=30652
2023-05-08 09:40:49.939 CEST [2288935] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.940 CEST [2288935] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:03:54.297 user=postgres database=spot_map host=78.139.198.206 port=30717
2023-05-08 09:40:49.945 CEST [2288894] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.946 CEST [2288894] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:04:22.930 user=postgres database=spot_map host=78.139.198.206 port=30505
2023-05-08 09:40:49.954 CEST [2288625] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.955 CEST [2288625] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:24.284 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=43260
2023-05-08 09:40:49.957 CEST [2288626] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.957 CEST [2288626] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:20.458 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=38542
2023-05-08 09:40:49.958 CEST [2288621] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.958 CEST [2288621] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:30.524 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=43258
2023-05-08 09:40:49.961 CEST [2288597] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:49.962 CEST [2288597] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:36.147 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=45146
2023-05-08 09:40:50.040 CEST [2288566] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.041 CEST [2288566] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:51.815 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=51912
2023-05-08 09:40:50.044 CEST [2288565] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.044 CEST [2288565] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:52.596 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=51898
2023-05-08 09:40:50.047 CEST [2288542] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.048 CEST [2288593] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.048 CEST [2288542] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:08:01.942 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=35978
2023-05-08 09:40:50.048 CEST [2288593] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:42.267 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=45138
2023-05-08 09:40:50.053 CEST [2287947] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.053 CEST [2287947] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:14:05.391 user=postgres database=spot_map host=78.139.198.206 port=28286
2023-05-08 09:40:50.124 CEST [2288567] postgres@spot_map FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2023-05-08 09:40:50.125 CEST [2288567] postgres@spot_map LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:07:49.487 user=postgres database=spot_map host=172.17.0.2 port=51920
2023-05-08 09:40:50.218 CEST [2287891] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 2287898) exited with exit code 1
2023-05-08 09:40:50.228 CEST [2287893] LOG:  shutting down
2023-05-08 09:40:50.232 CEST [2287893] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-05-08 09:40:50.439 CEST [2287893] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 120 buffers (0.7%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.186 s, sync=0.004 s, total=0.212 s; sync files=55, longest=0.001 >
2023-05-08 09:40:50.447 CEST [2287891] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Логи Spring Boot:

```
2023-05-09T07:37:16.629Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.shulpov.spots_app.config.JWTFilter   : filter authHeader=null
2023-05-09T07:37:16.668Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.shulpov.spots_app.config.JWTFilter   : to next filters
2023-05-09T09:00:55.443Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [{D79E94C5-70F0-46BD-965B-E17497CCB598}...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-09T09:05:26.508Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] com.shulpov.spots_app.config.JWTFilter   : filter authHeader=null
2023-05-09T09:05:26.513Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] com.shulpov.spots_app.config.JWTFilter   : to next filters
2023-05-09T09:05:26.720Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.s.s.controllers.AuthController         : /auth/register userDto.name=user1_name
Hibernate: select r1_0.id,r1_0.name,r1_0.code_name from roles r1_0 where r1_0.code_name=?
2023-05-09T09:05:57.048Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001
2023-05-09T09:05:57.050Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30022ms.
2023-05-09T09:05:57.051Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection to 185.249.227.104:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2023-05-09T09:05:57.515Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.4.jar!/:42.5.4]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Вот такие методы Rest API выполняются (CRUD операции с базой). Ничего не падает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. картинки в базе не храню, только информацию о них.

**Вопрос:** Как отследить причину падения базы? Она выключается как будто в случайный момент.

Comment: Может, что-то [отсюда](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183633/unexpected-postgresql-restart) натолкнёт на мысль?

Comment: define "падает". `received fast shutdown request` - это получен запрос на штатную остановку базы.

Comment: попробуйте логи настроить на DEBUG, еще момент системные (на самой ОС) настройки для постгрес, например сетевые (для большего числа клиентов, для лучшей пропускной способности, для увеличения буферов...). почитайте об этом. погуглить "how to prepare linux for postgres"